# Как работает компилятор языка C?

Tags: c, tcl

Мне нужно описание работы компилятора на естествeннoм языке составленное для того кто этого языка не знает. То есть учебник в духе "представь что ты компилятор, от этого двигаемся дальше."

Со вчерашнего дня учу этот язык. Синтаксис кажется хаосом, я не понимаю список действий которые проводит компилятор в процессе разбора, не понимаю к какой подсистеме языка относится выражение и что в результате передаётся элементам языка и функциям. Все эти символы которые непонятно как работают. Это очень сильно отличается от того к чему я привык в tcl в котором есть подстановщик,команды и их параметры.

Comment: Пример строки с "не понимаю к какой подсистеме языка относится выражение." покажите...

Comment: printf("Argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]); 

Вот например. Не понимаю на каком уровне обрабатывается это вот всё. Это всё параметры для printf которые передаются без изменений и он внутри себя их обрабатывает?

Comment: Элементарно: вызов функции (someName();). Параметры три штуки: "Argument %d: %s\n", i, argv[i]
Открываете документацию на функцию, смотрите что значат параметры. Как-то так.

Comment: википедя по printf это описывает. компилятор если честно, тут вообще ничего не делает. Т.е. он делает вызов функции printf и передает ей 3 аргумента - строку, i, и argv[i]. А вот разбор "абракадабры" в строке делает уже не компилятор, а сама функция printf. Так что в данном случае "хочу знать что делает компилятор" совершенно не решает проблему

Comment: Ну как минимум \n должна заменяться на символ перевод строки? Это делается подстановщиком-препроцессором?

Comment: @jto Ну оно и заменится. printf вообще довольно большая и сложная внутри функция, где-то в недрах будет вызов системной функции для вывода.

Comment: Спасибо. А препроцессор вообще мало чем там занимается? Что занимается подстановкой переменных?

Comment: Согласен, \n будет заменена компилятором. описания всех esc-последовательностей то же можно найти. И похоже вы их сами уже знаете, раз обратили на это внимание. Я тут сегодня на вопрос отвечал "Зачем при оптимизации копировать, инкрементировать, и копировать обратно?" вот там как раз про компилятор. И я не уверен, что настолько глубокое знание поможет при освоении языка, хотя оно не сомненно про то как он работает :)

Comment: Я просто после tcl, там очень многое через подстановку. Вот и догадался что \n заменяется компилятором. Спасибо.

Comment: Хотя я с вами согласен, я в свое время переходил на C с ассемблера :) Он меня пугал каким то непонятным синтаксисом. А когда дело дошло до адресов и указателей я вообще ни как не мог запомнить в каком случае что значат эти * и &. Пришлось писать себе шпаргалку перевод этих элементов синтаксиса на ассемблер. помогло. :)

Comment: После асма все указатели - вообще элементарно. Один раз посмотреть во что компиляться. А вот до асма не вкуривал...

Comment: Спасибо :), ох!

Comment: 'C' он гораздо более приближен к машине чем большинство других ЯП. Все что делается на чистом 'C' - это непосредственная работа с памятью и понимание логики работы самого железа в освоении очень мне помогало. И это же может усложнять переход с других ЯП которые максимально скрывают все "железные" действия от разработчика

Comment: @jto, измените подход, думайте черными ящиками. Та же функция printf в большинстве случаев превращается в ассемблерную кашу под конкретную систему, как и все остальное(даже больше, она не существует в языке, а реализована на уровне ОС). Вам без разницы как она делает свое дело, главное ЧТО ДЕЛАЕТ в точности согласно описанию в документации.

Comment: Так, и в if(1 == 1) подстановщиком услoвие на true не меняется перед тем как уйти в if? Получается что проверкой условия занимается if?

Comment: ну вот if - Это не функция. это элемент языка. У нее единственный параметр, вычисление значения которого даст true или flase. Тут как везде. По факту она будет преобразована в инструкции процессора по проверкам условий и переходу на разные участки кода по результатам

Comment: И 'C' хорош тем, что этих 'элементов языка' не особо много. собственно это if, while, for, do, switch, вроде ничего с круглыми скобками не забыл перечислить. Все остальное с круглыми скобками - функции

Comment: По С, ИМХО, лучше Кернигана/Ритчи ничего не придумали. В отличие от Страуструпа, они пишут понятно, довольно подробно расписывая многие тонкие моменты. А книг по языку "с точки зрения уомпилятора" Вы, думаю, не найдете, это надо читать книги по теории компиляторов/трансляторов, они существуют. Если повезет, попадется что-то с разбором С-подобного синтаксиса.

Comment: Если жу речь зашла о литературе, то мне больше нравится "Полный справочник по Си" Шилдта.

Comment: Ну в принципе tcl также простой язык. Перекормленный подстановщик, всё - фунция.
Но как понимаю теперь аналога подстановщика tcl в Си не существует.

Comment: Ох, спасибо. Но наверно "теория компиляторов для непрограммиста" - слишком странная книга чтобы она могла существовать.

Comment: @AlexKrass, Справочник и учебник - все же два совершенно разных человека. Учиться по спавочнику с 0 - практически невозможно, а для специалиста, пусть даже самого начального уровня он может быть полезнее самого хорошего учебгика.

Comment: @jto в некотором виде подстановщик существует(отдаленно напоминающий его механизм). Знакомство с ним как правило люди переносят крайне тяжело, называется он "указатель". В случае простых типов он всегда работает автоматически, вам не надо явно писать как в tcl `if($a == 1)`, достаточно `if(a == 1)`, но иногда бывает обращение по указателю `if(*a == 1)`.

Comment: @andy.37 а Вы попробуйте перелистать и сравнить обе книги. Как по мне K&R не далеко ушли от справочника(была в то время частая традиция писать учебники "научно") и имеют ряд проблем с порядком  изложения.

Answer (score 9):

Вы должны думать следующим образом.

1. Общая картина. Компилируются C-файлы по отдельности, компилятор не знает ничего о других файлах, если это не указано в файле явно. Другие файлы «втягиваются» препроцессором. (Для пуристов, да, я могу скормить и .h компилятору через Makefile, не будем усложнять картину без надобности.)
2. Препроцессор. Он проходится по коду и производит тупые текстовые макроподстановки. `#define X(Y, Z) for (int i = 0; i < Y; i = i * Z)` заставляет `X(10, 2 + 1)` превращаться в `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i = i * 2 + 1)`. Препроцессор, однако, знает о строках, и не проводит макроподстановки внутри них. Также он применяет `#include` путём механического включения в это место файла.
3. Препроцессор строк. Внутри строковых и символьных литералов некоторые последовательности символов заменяются на другие. Например, `\n` заменяется на символ с кодом 10. Также, для литералов широких строк (`wchar_t*`) может применяться перекодировка из character set'а исходного файла в UCS-2 или UCS-4, в зависимости от компилятора.
4. Собственно компилятор. Никакой магии у компилятора нет. Есть ключевые слова (`for`, `if`, etc.) и функции. Например, `printf` — это функция (из стандартной библиотеки), запись `printf("%d\n", 15);` производит в скомпилированном коде вызов функции `printf` и передачу ей параметров `"%d\n"` и `15`. Точно так же вызов `printf("%d\n", "");` производит в вызов функции `printf` с параметрами `"%d\n"` и `""` (этот вызов завершится с ошибкой времени выполнения). Компилятор знает точную семантику форматной строки `printf` и *имеет право* выдать подсказку, если он видит, что типы параметров не подходят к форматной строке.
5. Оптимизатор. Он имеет право внутри заменить любую конструкцию на более эффективную, пользуясь правилом as if: если с точки зрения конечного вывода и видимых пользователю значений это не меняет результат, преобразование допустимо. Пример: если у вас есть длинное вычисление без побочных эффектов, результатом которого вы не пользуетесь (то есть, не выводите его), оптимизатор имеет право выкинуть его. И также имеет право и не выкидывать. Например, порядок вычисления слагаемых в выражении `A() + B()` не определён, и даже если функции `A` и `B` имеют побочные эффекты, оптимизатор имеет право вычислять их в любом порядке, может быть даже вперемешку. Если вы хотите гарантировать, что `A()` вычислится строго перед `B()`, пользуйтесь явной дополнительной переменной.
6. Undefined behaviour. Here be dragons. Существует достаточно большой набор рантайм-ситуаций (например: разыменовние нулевого указателя, выход за границу массива (!) или знаковое переполнение), когда компилятор перестаёт нести ответственность за результат. Компилятор имеет право предполагать, что такого никогда не случится, делать из этого нетривиальные умозаключения, и применять их для упрощения кода. Например: для кода

   ```
   int m[1];
   if (cond)
   {
       printf("Хе-хе\n");
       return;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   {
       m[i] = 0;
   }
   ```

   компилятор имеет право предположить, что обращение `m[1]` никогда не происходит, поэтому цикл не выполняется, поэтому код должен выйти на раннем `return`, поэтому `cond` обязательно равно `true`, значит, его можно не вычислять, и упростить всю функцию до

   ```
   printf("Хе-хе\n");
   ```

Comment: кстати, пример с `printf` вообще довольно любопытен. Я, например, каким образом `printf` НЕ противоречит синтаксису С. Там же нет функций с произвольным числом аргументов. Если кто даст ссылку с описанием ее устройства "изнутри" что-ли (но не на код, не уверен, что есть код `printf` на С), буду весьма признателен

Comment: @andy.37 В C есть функции с переменным числом аргументов, при описании последний параметр объявляется как '...'

Comment: @andy.37 Вот первое что дал гугл: http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/418970.1

Comment: @Mike, да уж, позор на мою седую голову. Забыл(((. Теперь, в целом понятно.

Comment: @VladD  "Вы должны думать следующим образом" - это из нового закона Государственной Думы относительно граждан России?:)

Comment: VladD В 6 пункте как то непонятна причинно следственная связь. cond не объявлен и я не уверен, что он true. Как вы заключили, что раз цикл после if не выполняется, то cond точно true. Хотя если бы он был false - то цикл бы выполнился. А как зависит выполнение цикла от обращения к m[i], по моему наоборот, только на основании того что цикл не выполнится можно заключить, что m не используется

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Да! Теперь я спалился, и вы знаете, кто их разрабатывает. <s>Мне придётся всех убить.</s>

Comment: @Mike: Смотрите. Компилятор **имеет право** исходить из того, что UB не будет. Он смотрит, что если цикл начнёт выполняться, то UB будет обязательно, поэтому он вправе считать, что цикл выполняться не начнёт. Отсюда он вправе считать, что flow зайдёт внутрь `if`'а. Отсюда он вправе считать, что `cond != 0`. Отсюда он вправе вычислить `cond` только для побочных эффектов, и не смотреть на значение (т. к. он знает, что оно будет `!= 0`), или если он видит, что побочных эффектов нет, то вовсе не считать его.

Comment: @VladD ок, так понятнее. Тогда почему он _имеет право_. Моя логика мне подсказывает, что он не должен делать столь далеко идущих предположений не основываясь на конкретных фактах. Факта, что m далее не используется мне кажется недостаточно

Comment: @Mike: Насколько я понимаю, он не пользуется тем фактом, что `m` дальше не используется. Он просто пользуется тем, что последняя итерация цикла вызывает UB.

Comment: @Mike: По поводу _имеет право_, сейчас попробую найти пруфы.

Comment: @VladD Еще вчера я бы очень сильно сомневался в таком умном его поведении, но ответив вчера на тот вопрос по оптимизатору я уже понимаю, что он и не такое в принципе может предсказывать :) Я вот тут как раз опасаюсь за один момент в моем коде, не зааптимизуруют ли его слишком сильно: if(a) { pthread_lock(m); if(a) ... }. Я проверял, если функцию не вызывать, то `a ` проверяется только 1 раз, но когда функция есть - то оба раза. Вот я боюсь а не могут ли какие нибудь настройки заставить компилятор опустить повторную проверку, имеет ли компилятор на это право

Comment: @Mike: [Стандарт C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf), 1.9/4, говорит: This International Standard imposes no requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined behavior. По поводу менее формального определения, вот замечательная серия статей: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 (сорри, что отсылаю к длинному тексту, сам лучше объяснить не смогу).

Comment: @Mike: Компилятор обычно не имеет права переносить оптимизацию через lock и тому подобные конструкции. Но double-checked locking всё равно не очень хорошая идея: http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf

Comment: @Mike: Ещё насчёт того, какие конкретно оптимизации при помощи UB делает clang: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @VladD Спасибо. буду переваривать :)